# Shipping Lanes - Waypoints flat file

Tags: data-request

appreciate there are a number of solutions that provide shape data or other visualisations but I am looking for a list of global maritime shipping routes as a list of long/lat waypoints.

Does anyone know of an open source database that provides this?  Or is there clear instructions on how to convert a shape data file into a flat file of co-ordinates?

I am trying to show how goods move by sea between two ports on a map.  It currently has just a straight line between the two points over land but I want to show it via a more accurate sea route.

Thanks,

Dan.

Thanks,

Daniel.